# Cellspacing in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-2013

I have this table where I need spacing between the cells:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5px">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100"/></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100"/></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100"/></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 the spacing isn't correct while in other clients it looks just fine.

Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013:
[image: Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013]

Other clients:
[image: Other clients]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5px">
```

should be

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
```